Show that classmethod only callable on and returning child classes
Given a class set up something like this:
class Parent:
    _GET_URL = None

    @classmethod
    def get_object(cls) -> typing.Self:
        requests.get(cls._GET_URL)

and
class Child(Parent):
    _GET_URL = "https://some-url-to-child.me"

Similar URLs are set up for all child classes.
How do I typehint it such that

it's obvious that the get_object method can only be callable by calling it on a child class (and therefore getting the object from their URL)
the linter understands the returned object is of Child type. Using PyCharm, it only recognizes the result of Child.get_object() as 'Parent'

Tried using both typing.Self and ChildObject = TypeVar('ChildObject', bounds="Parent") with no results. No idea how to achieve 1)

What would the Gang of Four ask ? Is a class method a contract common and available to all subclasses and instances ? Or maybe you need an abstract method ? In both cases, if yes, then ... the answer seems pretty obvious. If the return type is a specific abstraction/interface too, it does not change the outcome, only the specified type itself. Unless I'm missing something not stated in the question ?!

I have correct type annotations. PyCharm displays child: Child = Child. get_object() on hover

The class method is a common method available on all child classes, but not on the parent class itself.

Is there any reason to have it as a class method?  It seems to be returning a response object.

I'm not sure but seems worth reading https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod vs https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod and also https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation

Is there a missing return cls in the function?

This might be too simple an example, but it seems like Parent.get_object should just be a regular function that receives a URL as an argument. The classes are just syntactic overhead that doesn't really contribute anything.

I believe you're just missing the return cls() line or similar, as noted in one of the comments. You may wish to provide some arguments to this but without seeing the __init__ it's difficult to add the syntax. The Self type hint is used to refer to when a classmethod (or other method) returns an instance of the current class:
import typing

def some_func(s: str):
    print(s)

class Parent:
    _GET_URL: typing.ClassVar[str]
    @classmethod
    def get_object(cls) -> typing.Self:
        some_func(cls._GET_URL)
        return cls()

class Child(Parent):
    _GET_URL = "https://some-url-to-child.me"

x = Child.get_object()
typing.reveal_type(x) # Displays Child as expected

Also I've added the type hint for _GET_URL here - it's a required Class Variable (see here). Hope this is useful!
